# Finding the equation of tangent plane to a surface represented by vector-valued function

Tags: calculus, vectors

Given r(u,v) = *u*i + *v*j + sqrt(*u v*)k, how do I find the equation of the tangent plane at point (1,1,1). This looks simple, but how would I obtain the gradient of the function given which is in vector form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The the tangent vectors at the point $(1,1,1)=(u,v,\sqrt{uv})\implies u=v=1$
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}(1,1)=\left(1,0,\frac{v}{2\sqrt{uv}}\right)\vert_{u=11,v=1}=(1,0,1/2)\\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}(1,1)=\left(0,1,\frac{v}{2\sqrt{uv}}\right)\vert_{u=1,v=1}=(0,1,1/2)\\
$$
What does the cross product of the two tangent vectors which define the tangent plane at the point $(1,1,1)$ give you?

Comment: It will give you a normal vector of the plane: (-1/2,-1/2,-1). Which I should make the equation of the plane: -1/2(x-1) - 1/2(y-1) + 1(z-1) = 0. Thanks for your help!

Comment: correct. Certainly,

Answer (score 0):

$(\frac {\partial x}{\partial u},\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial z}{\partial u})$ is a vector in the tangent plane

$(\frac {\partial x}{\partial v},\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial z}{\partial v})$ is also a vector in the tangent plane.

Their cross product will be normal to the tangent plane.